# Replace values that starts with "<" in a data frame in r

Tags: r

I am new to R and would like some assistance on replacing multiple values in a large dataset with many variables to NA at once in r.

I want all the cells with "<**0.01, <0.02, and many others with < sign at the beginning**" to be changed to NA.
[image: Data screenshot]

How do I do it at once? Here is a screenshot of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `gsub` with a regular expression to replace every string starting with a "<" with NA.

```r
x <- c("<0.01", "0.027", "<0.01", "<0.01", "0.2", "0.22", "0.04", "0.09")
gsub("<.*", NA, x)
# [1] NA      "0.027" NA      NA      "0.2"   "0.22"  "0.04"  "0.09"
```

Comment: Thank you @Oxbowerce, I tried your suggestion but nothing changed. They still have the < sign.

Comment: Could you export a sample of your dataframe using `dput(head(x, 5))` where `x` is the name of your dataframe and paste it here?

Comment: `structure(list(Date = c("43887", "43885"), Year = c(2020, 2020
), Month = c(2, 2), Day = c(26, 24), pH = c("8.3000000000000007", 
"8.1"), Colour = c("17", "<1"), Conductivity = c("48.9", "55.9"
), SO4 = c("34", "56"), NO3 = c("1.1000000000000001", "1.2"), 
    NO2 = c("<0.1", "<0.1"), Fe = c("0.04", "0.02"), Mn = c("0.01", 
    "<0.01"), Cu = c("<0.01", "<0.01"), Zn = c("<0.01", "0.01"
    ), Cd = c("<0.01", "<0.01")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))`

Comment: How are you executing the code? Using `gsub("<.*", NA, x$Colour)` works perfectly fine for me, returning `"17" NA ` for `"17", "<1"`.

Comment: I see now, I was not specifying the column name. Thank you very much, I will do it like that from now on (each column separately).